# Strange pattern in numbers why is the series of absolute differences always 0?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, pattern-recognition, intuitionistic-logic

Put any four numbers in a row, say,

77          73           29          179.

Under the first number write the difference between it and the second number. Under the second number put the difference between it and the third. Under the third put its difference from the fourth, and under the fourth, its difference from the first. We are concerned only with absolute differences, differences that are positive. The procedure gives a new set of four numbers, like so:

77          73           29          179

04          44           150        102

Repeat the procedure as long as possible. The result is:

77          73           29        179

04          44           150        102

40          106         48          98

66          58           50          58

08          08          08          08

0             0             0            0

It is not a remarkable coincidence. This will happen with any set of 4 numbers. You will always reach 0.

Why does it always happen?
I know the formal proof but I am still unable to grasp it intuitively, exactly why does it happen? Can anyone explain it in simple terms without much formalities?

Comment: You need to pay attention to the formal proof. Usually, they come along with the main ideas. From what I see is that the bigger number always decrease. A set of strictly decreasing numbers always reach $0.$

Comment: Does this answer your question?   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154926/subtraction-puzzle-conjecture

Comment: @RajatKumar.. that's a nice question (+1)... it reminds me of Collatz (even if this involves four numbers)

Comment: Thanks guys, I got so much material to study from!